# calculate average rating from mysql and show it as a graph

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to solve this. As I am just in a learning phase of PHP/Mysql.

I have a php feedback form as a rating system from 1-5. You can find my form here http://innovatrix.co.in/feedback_priyajit/feedback%20form1.html

Every time a user provide feedback it saves form values into a mysql database. Below is my database structure.

[image]

Now I want to calculate average data of every row (like waiting) and show it on a php file as a graph and also **separate graph for every option but on a same page.**

I know I can use query `SELECT AVG(waiting) FROM feedback` to get an average of "*waiting*"

But how can I do this for every options from a same file and also show it as a graph. Database will be updated frequently, thus it should reflect the graph also.

Please help me with a concept for achieving this.

Below is my php file which I am using to store form values into database.

```
<title>process</title>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user_name="pramir_feedback";
$pwd="feedback";
$database_name="pramir_feedback";
$db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd);
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
$waiting = $_POST['radio1'];
$consultation = $_POST['radio2'];
$preoperative = $_POST['radio3'];
$specialists = $_POST['radio4'];
$assistants = $_POST['radio5'];
$painful = $_POST['radio6'];
$operatingroom = $_POST['radio7'];
$thought = $_POST['radio8'];
$recommend = $_POST['radio9'];
$suggestions = $_POST['suggestions'];
$query = "insert into feedback (waiting, consultation, preoperative, specialists, assistants, painful, operatingroom, thought, recommend, suggestions) values ('" . $waiting . "', '" . $consultation . "', '" . $preoperative . "', '" . $specialists . "', '" . $assistants . "', '" . $painful . "', '" . $operatingroom . "', '" . $thought . "', '" . $recommend . "', '" . $suggestions . "')";
if (mysql_error() > "") print mysql_error() . "<br>";
$qresult = mysql_query($query);
echo "<h1>Thank you for submitting your details!</h1>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the averages in one query, you can just delimit them with commas.

```
SELECT AVG(waiting), AVG(consultation), AVG(preoperative), AVG(specialists), ...... FROM feedback
```

If you want to know how to put them in a graph, take a look at one of the many jQuery graph or plot makers, like: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php